# Azure Functions ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-functions, modulenotfounderror

```
[2023-04-27T08:21:37.499Z] Executing 'Functions.func-test' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=44347c87-36a7-4415-bbe8-63a922af57bc)
[2023-04-27T08:21:37.590Z] Executed 'Functions.func-test' (Failed, Id=44347c87-36a7-4415-bbe8-63a922af57bc, Duration=125ms)
[2023-04-27T08:21:37.591Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.func-test. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 357, in _handle__function_load_request
    func = loader.load_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 48, in call
    raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 44, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 132, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\anandu.balachandran\AzureFunctionTest\func-test\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
```

sample code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

pandas lib is mentioned in the requirements.txt

when the code deployed to function app its working

but while trying to debug the code in **local** its not working - can see the pandas getting installed while in debug mode, if pandas import removed I can debug the code and trigger the http request using postman (only issue with pandas package)

My requirements.txt file contains

```
pandas==2.0.1
numpy
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
openai[embeddings]
requests
```

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I was getting the same error for Pandas module.*

[image]

It could be because the `pandas` module is not installed correctly in the local environment.

Run the below command and check if it helps to fix the issue. It worked for me:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`.

[image]

[image]

***Result:***

Then try debugging and check if the issue persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you try to create a new project with the same packages and check if the issue persists?

Comment: Still the same error. When I go with cmd terminal its working using `func host start`

Comment: Can you try 'Run without debugging' and check if it works?